# How to update Blazor UI for a specific user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, signalr, blazor

So I got two Servers running. **Server A** is doing different calculations on a per-user-basis (so the Server calculates different things for different users). **Server B** is a Blazor Server that should display the calculation results for each user. **Server A** already knows who is connected and waiting for their results (let's just say via a unique ID for simplicity).

I'm now searching for a way that **Server A** can tell **Server B** something like "here's the result **X** for user ID **Y** please show it to him". The Blazor Server should then just update the page for the user with the given ID.

I tried working with SignalR and managed to communicate between both servers but I don't know how to only update the data for one specific user connected to the Blazor server.

Comment: The server B must know the correlation between the unique ID on server A and the users that are "connected" to server B. When the server A finish the calculation, must call server B with the resutl and the userId, then server B send a push notification to the user that request the calculation and update the page with the result

Comment: @HenkHolterman It's a bit complicated since everything is running in a "game context" if you will. So the player loads the website that's served by the Blazor Server (Server B) inside the game. The player then tells the website it's unique ID for future authentication (password checks are done elsewhere). Server B currently got a "StateService" Class (added as scoped)  that holds that unique ID and uses it request information from Server A (which seems to be working fine already but I couldn't test with multiple users yet).

Comment: @Johna That sounds exactly like what I'm trying to accomplish. How would I got about that? Is it enough to have a singleton with a dictionary or something that links each connected user to it's unique ID? How do I get the connected users or how can I add a user together with it's unique ID to the list after first render? Thanks so far. :)

Comment: I'd do something like this (may be you already know this): If you are using something like jwt, you can put the userId inside it and use on both servers. Using signalr you have a way to know who is each user. That information must be correlated to the unique id inside the jwt.If the server B is generating the jwt you can put the user signalR identification directly (if u know it at that time), if not, you must save the correlation between both of them the first time the user call the server B (or in a particular method after that?), and may be store in the StateService class?